# IDistributedCache in .net core 2.0 is not shared between calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm developing .NET Core 2.0 Web API and trying to use `IDistributedCache` to keep some data between different calls. 
For this task I created wrapper and registered it as a singleton in Startup.cs file in order to use dependency injection in my controllers.

This is how the wrapper looks (simplified):

```
public interface ICacheWrapper
  {
    Task Set<T>(string name, T obj);

    Task<T> TryGet<T>(string name);
  }

  public class CacheWrapper : ICacheWrapper
  {
    private readonly IDistributedCache _cache;

    private readonly TimeSpan _defaultOffset = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0);

    public CacheWrapper(IDistributedCache cache)
    {
      _cache = cache;
    }
    public async Task Set<T>(string name, T obj)
    {
      await DoSet(name, obj);
    }
    public async Task<T> TryGet<T>(string name)
    {
      var data = await Get<T>(name);
    }   
     private async Task DoSet<T>(string name, T obj)
    {
      var binFormatter = new BinaryConverter();
      var array = binFormatter.Serialize(obj);
      var options = new DistributedCacheEntryOptions { SlidingExpiration = _defaultOffset };
      await _cache.SetAsync(name, array, options);
    }

    private async Task<T> Get<T>(string name)
    {
      var binFormatter = new BinaryConverter();
      var data = await _cache.GetAsync(name);
      if (data == null)
      {
        return default(T);
      }
      var obj = binFormatter.Deserialize<T>(data);
      return obj;
    }
}
```

I also added this line to my Startup.cs file: `services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();`

The problem is: between each API call `IDistributedCache` object seems to reset - it does not contain any data. What should I do to keep the cache between calls?

*Edit*: I can confirm that adding to cache works in scope of one call, after doing `SetAsync` cache contains one item.

*Edit2* This is how I register my wrapper : `services.AddSingleton<ICacheWrapper, CacheWrapper>();`

Comment: Can you share how you are registering the wrapper with the IoC container?

Comment: @TomElmore Added this to my question

Comment: And all calls are to the same service? Because despite its name, cache registered with `AddDistributedMemoryCache` is not really distributed.

Comment: @Evk yes, the same controller, the same endpoint, the same service (local .exe)

Comment: Im wondering if you really need the wrapper as a singleton.. could you try registering with a normal lifecycle and see if that changes anything?

Comment: @TomElmore didn't help. It seems like every time I'm injecting `ICacheWrapper` it calls new `IDistributedCache` object

Comment: Are you sure no further configuration is needed? Normally you need to config a redis instance or SQL server for the AddDistributedCache method. Did you try to switch to AddMemoryCache (for non distributed caching but service wide caching)?

Comment: @pr177 I am not sure but [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.memorycacheservicecollectionextensions.adddistributedmemorycache?view=aspnetcore-2.0) states that this is a way to go. I did try IMemoryCache but it resulted in the same behavior.

Comment: I couldn´t believe that this don´t work, so I set it up. It worked like intended. The only thing I can´t reproduce is your BinaryConverter and your Controller logic. Could you add your Controller? Are you sure to set a good key for storing?